# How show that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of the domain of a function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ defined $\forall x\neq 0$. How I can prove that $x_0=0$ is an accumulation point for $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x\neq 0\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of accumulation point, for every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ (recall you can prove it for elements of the basis, so you can prove this claim for every open interval) that contains $x=0$, you can show that it contains another point of your set $A$.

Another hint may be to construct a sequence of points $x_n \in A$ converging to $0$, for example pick the sequence $x_n =1/n \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: How I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, know your definitions:

We define the open ball centred around $x$; denoted $B(x;r)$ in $\Bbb R$ as the set $\bigg\{y \in\Bbb R\ \bigg|\  |x-y|< r\bigg\}$, where $r>0$. In higher dimensions with different metrics, the definition is similar.

This is represented in $\Bbb R$ by the set $(x-r, x+r)$.

Now, $x_0$ is an *accumulation point* of a set $A$ if every open ball centred around $x_0$ contains a point in $A$ that is distinct from $x_0$. In other words, you need to show that $$A\cap B(0; r) \neq \emptyset$$ for each $r>0$. Clearly, this is the case, as $A=\Bbb R/ \{0\}$, since $0$ is the only missing point from $A$, we can find a point in any non-empty ball that is non-zero, and hence in $A$.